# How to improve the speed of display using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, cython, pyqtgraph

I have 2 files created, one a .pyx file with a class named AndorCamersSDK which has a function named LiveAcquisition(). The second file, a .py file with a Class AndorCameraGUI which makes use of Tkinter to create a GUI. This class has function LivePlot(), and RepeatPlot().Inside LiveAcquisition() I am acquiring N number of frames and after acquiring each frame I need to display it using  LivePlot() and RepeatPlot(). Without the display, just acquiring and storing for 300 frames takes 6.2 for execution, which is fine by me. But When I start displaying even for 100 frames it takes 54sec. I need to acquire and display within 6 sec for 300 frames. How do I solve this?

File 1: .pyx code ; Present inside class AndorCameraSDK

```
def  LiveAcquisition(self):
    for i in range(no_of_frames): 
        data[i,:,:] = PyArray_NewFromDescr(<PyTypeObject *> np.ndarray, np.dtype('<H'), 2,dims, strides,pBuf, np.NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS, None)
        if (i==0):
            self.master.LivePlot(data[i,:,:])
        elif (i==2) or (i==15) or (i ==65) or (i ==96):
            self.master.RepeatPlot(data[i,:,:])
        else:
            pass
```

File 2 : .py code; Below functions are present inside a class named AndorCameraGUI

```
def LivePlot(self,image):
    self.count = 0
    self.fig = Figure(figsize = (4, 5))
    self.fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:light grey') # When this is removed a white color is seen in the background of the figure
    self.a = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.a.set_xlim([0, self.image_width/int(self.HBin)])
    self.a.set_ylim([0, self.image_height/int(self.VBin)])
    image = image.transpose()
    self.a.imshow(image,'gray')
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,self.master)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side =LEFT)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas,self.master)
    self.toolbar.update()
    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = LEFT)# change this to TOP so thee the navigation toolbar on the left down

def RepeatPlot(self,image):
    image = image.transpose()
    self.a.imshow(image,'gray')
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: `def RepeatPlot(self,image):
        self.im.set_data(image)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.update()`
When I changed RepeatPlot() to this , speed has been drastically improved. Now it takes 10.4 seconds to acquire 100 image, which I need it to be within 6 seconds. Is there a way to make it more faster

Comment: could pyqtgraph be used in tkinter GUI to solve this ?

Comment: I second aishwaya on this, you will love pyqtgraph for this. In fact, I built a GUI for lasers and an ANDOR camera with pyqtgraph. The code is [here](https://github.com/fedebarabas/tormenta). Use it if you find it useful

Comment: @Federico, thank you for the link. Glad at least someone replied back.